# Syntax Error Hibernate - unexpected token: ON

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've got three tables:
cameras - [id, address, city, url, server_name, …]
vlc - [id, camera_id (which is equal to id in cameras), server_name, port, status]
categories - [id, name]

Hear is my MySQl Syntax, which gave me good result:

```
"SELECT vlc.camera_id, vlc.url, vlc.port,"
 + " vlc.server_name, cameras.address, cameras.city, categories.name FROM vlc AS vlc" +
 " INNER JOIN cameras ON vlc.camera_id = cameras.id" +
 " INNER JOIN categories ON cameras.category_id = categories.id"
 + " WHERE vlc.status = 'active' AND ")
```

But in Hibernate I got this Syntax error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 141
```

Anyone can help? I know that it may be obvious, but I can not find a solution.

EDIT:
I changed to:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<VLC> getVLCs() {
    return getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT vlc.camera_id, vlc.url, vlc.port,"
                    + " vlc.server_name, cameras.address, cameras.city, categories.name FROM vlc AS vlc" +
                    " INNER JOIN cameras ON vlc.camera_id = cameras.id" +
                    " INNER JOIN categories ON cameras.category_id = categories.id"
                    + " WHERE vlc.status = 'active'").list();
}
```

But now I got:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to pl.humandevice.model.VLC
```

I have to change something in my classes propably

Comment: Are you trying to use native queries or HQL?

Comment: Show where you use this query. Be sure that you using `createSQLQuery` method, not `createQuery`

Comment: probably HQL statements

Comment: can you please provide some more code to make write answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You changed it to native SQL but you are making a projection with attributes from both VLC and camera objects, You need to either restrict the select to VLC objects so Hibernate knows how to map the requested attribute list into VLC objects, or explicitly convert them yourself by receiving a List of OBject[] then selecting each value yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `createSQLQuery` instead `createQuery`.
Second one is for HQL (Hibernate Query Language) instead of SQL.

**UPD:**
Using SQL hibernate can't wrap recived data to objects. That's why you have to use [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).

E.G.:

```
public List<VLC> getVLCs() {
    return getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Cat as cat inner join fetch cat.mate left join fetch cat.kittens").list();
}
```

Where Cat is **Class mapped to table**.

Comment: what is difference between them ??

Comment: HQL - for objects mapped to tables, SQL for tables.